# Template class instantiation error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a class template with a parametrized constructor.

```
template <typename value_t>
class A
{
  protected:

    std::vector<value_t> data;
    int n;

  public:

    A(const int num):n(num) {}
};
```

And I'm trying to instantiate this way

```
class B
{
  protected:
    A<float> position(256);

  public:
    B() {}
};
```

Which leads to the following error in MSVC (Visual Studio 2012)

**IntelliSense: expected a type specifier**

Any idea?

Comment: I'm assuming VertexStream(...) should be A(...) in your example, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass parameters to the constructors of members in the constructor of the owning class. So in your case you need to pass the value `256` to your `position` member in the constructor for B. The working code is as follows:

```
#include <vector>
template <typename value_t>
class A
{
  protected:

    std::vector<value_t> data;
    int n;

  public:

    A(const int num):n(num) 
    {}
};

class B
{
  protected:
    A<float> position;

  public:
    B()  : position(256)
    {}
};
```

Comment: Doesn't C++11 introduce member initializer? Maybe the error is due to non-conformance of VS2012, not the programmer.

Comment: @CR, It's completely a VS 2012 NSDMI issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
A<float> position(256);
```

should be

```
A<float> position{256};
//               ^   ^
```

But I'm not sure that VS2012 support this C++11 feature...

Otherwise, you can use the [*member-initialization-list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to do that:

```
class B
{
  protected:
    A<float> position;
    //               ^

  public:
    B() : position(256)
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {}
};
```